# Autotextview search function confusion

Tags: android

Hello I have implemented Autotextview search in my application. 
The problem i am facing is that sometimes the search is done in between the string as in the image below :

[image]

Like i wrote "J' in the field the values that were displayed contained 'J'

Now when i type "HDF"
i get the following result :

[image]

As you can see in the last the value coming is "HDF - HDFC BANK LTD"
when i type 'HDF'

Now when i type "HDFC"

i should get "HDF - HDFC BANK LTD" as it contains "HDFC"
but i get this result :

[image]

As there are 2 values in the list, ie "HDF - HDFC BANK LTD" and "HDFC BANK". so "HDFC BANK" is shown is correct but why we dont get "HDF - HDFC BANK LTD". why is that so?

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: Are you doing the filtering or just supplying strings to autocompletetextview?

Comment: just applying the strings.

Comment: Write your own adapter with custom filter as you need.

Comment: can you provide a link or code you have used?

Comment: and my doubt is that why is that so that the search results are not constant?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Adapter like this :

Here `List<SearchSuggestion> suggestionList` is my list of custom Search Suggestion class. You can use String instead and make changes accordingly.

```
public class SearchSuggestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchSuggestion> implements Filterable {

private Context mContext;
private List<SearchSuggestion> mSuggestionList;
private List<SearchSuggestion> mFilteredSuggestionList;

public SearchSuggestionAdapter(Context context, List<SearchSuggestion> suggestionList) {
    super(context, -1);
    mContext = context;
    mSuggestionList = suggestionList;
    mFilteredSuggestionList = mSuggestionList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.mSuggestionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_text);
        viewHolder.mSuggestionImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    SearchSuggestion searchSuggestion = mFilteredSuggestionList.get(position);
    viewHolder.mSuggestionTextView.setText(searchSuggestion.getName());
    viewHolder.mSuggestionImage.setImageResource(searchSuggestion.isTag() ? R.drawable.suggestion_tag_icon : R.drawable.suggestion_project_icon);
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    private ImageView mSuggestionImage;
    private TextView mSuggestionTextView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFilteredSuggestionList.size();
}

@Override
public SearchSuggestion getItem(int position) {
    return mFilteredSuggestionList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                List<SearchSuggestion> tempFilteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (SearchSuggestion suggestion : mSuggestionList) {
                    String name = suggestion.getName();
                    if (name != null && name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        tempFilteredList.add(suggestion);
                    }
                }
                results.values = tempFilteredList;
                results.count = tempFilteredList.size();
            } else {
                results.values = mSuggestionList;
                results.count = mSuggestionList.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.values != null) {
                mFilteredSuggestionList = (ArrayList<SearchSuggestion>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. i will try this. but you can figure out what problem is this?

Comment: Don't know what is happening internally, might be string comparision problem. Custom adapters works like charm. Hope this Helps.